# File.Exists returns true, but File.Encrypt throws

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, io

I have deployed new ASP.NET Core 3.1 application on my Windows Server 2016 for the first time. However, the application crashes on startup with 500.30 error and exception thrown during appsettings.json encryption. As you can see in the snippet below, `File.Exists` returns true, however, in `File.Encrypt` an exception is thrown. I have ensured that user account defined in app pool in IIS has Full Control on folder, but it does not seem to have any effect.

```
    private static void EncryptAppSettings()
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "appsettings.json");
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.Encrypt(path); // Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: Element not found. : 'P:\Balsam\appsettings.json'
        }
    }
```

The file itself of course exists under specified path.
Full information from event viewer:

```
Application: Balsam.Front.exe
CoreCLR Version: 4.700.20.41105
.NET Core Version: 3.1.8
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.IOException: Element not found. : 'P:\Balsam\appsettings.json'
   at System.IO.FileSystem.ThrowExceptionEncryptDecryptFail(String fullPath)
   at System.IO.FileSystem.Encrypt(String path)
   at System.IO.File.Encrypt(String path)
   at Balsam.Front.Program.EncryptAppSettings() in P:\JENKINS\x\Balsam.Front\Program.cs:line 40
   at Balsam.Front.Program.Main(String[] args) in P:\JENKINS\x\Balsam.Front\Program.cs:line 16
```

Why does `File.Encrypt` throw an exception if `File.Exists` returns true?

Comment: Here's a [seemingly related bug in .Net Core](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30144) (although that's supposedly fixed now).

Comment: Service user has read _and_write privileges to the folder/file?

Comment: @Fildor yes, every permission I could have set is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think the issue is with the code **you've written** based on the docs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=netcore-3.1
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.encrypt?view=netcore-3.1

Reading particularly about the exceptions File.Encrypt throws, when it's an IO exception the issue isn't that the file can't be found (it's got a load of other exceptions for that).

> IOException An I/O error occurred while opening the file.
>
> -or-
>
> This operation is not supported on the current platform.

So, not really sure what the issue is. There are exceptions for all the other common issues thrown by File.Encrypt, so I guess the issue is something else entirely.

Maybe it's a bug in .NET Core similar to what's been mentioned in the comments? Maybe there is an issue with one of the services that .NET requires? Either way, this error isn't something we can clearly address as far as I'm aware.

I'd raise a bug on git. Perhaps link it in this answer so future people who have this issue have a bit more visibility if that's the path you choose.

Comment: I created issue. If any solution appears, I will add it as answer later, if any solution is offered. https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/5192

Comment: As you can see in comment to issue, problem is not related to .NET itself, as it is default message coming from WinAPI. I will follow up with solution as soon as sysadmins find root cause.

Comment: With  what `NetMage` mentioned,EncryptFileW,you can refer to [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sdk-api/blob/d9129690c6053d898a543ee8a8c21c633dc586f5/sdk-api-src/content/winbase/nf-winbase-encryptfilew.md).Maybe you can find something useful with it.